# Qt : QWheelEvent does not refer to a value

Tags: qt

I'm trying to create a Ctrl + Mousewheel macro to zoom in and out of an image view in my application.

Currently I am trying to use the current code:

```
new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::CTRL + QWidget::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event)), this, SLOT(zoom()));
```

However I get the error `QWheelEvent does not refer to a value`. I have all the necessary includes in my header file so I do not understand why I'm getting the error.

Is it illegal to bind the widget event in conjunction within a `QKeySequence`? If so, how should I handle the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `QKeySequence` in this way. You should reimplement `wheelEvent` or use next event filter (it is example how to zoom in/out in `textEdit`, you can use this code for your special case):

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if(obj == ui->plainTextEdit && event->type() == QEvent::Wheel )
    {
        QWheelEvent *wheel = static_cast<QWheelEvent*>(event);
        if( wheel->modifiers() == Qt::ControlModifier )
            if(wheel->delta() > 0)
                ui->plainTextEdit->zoomIn(2);
            else
                ui->plainTextEdit->zoomOut(2);
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

Main idea: catch wheel event and check is `Ctrl` modifier is pressed.

To use `eventFilter` you should also:

```
protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);//in header
```

and

```
qApp->installEventFilter(this);//in constructor
```

Note: I showed example with event filter because it is not require subclassing, it is not better or something else, reimplement `wheelEvent` with similar code and you will get absolutely same result.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I bind the event so it fires only if the Ctrl key is down too though?

Comment: Oh wait I see, the wheel->modifiers() line handles that?